# Android change activity event

Tags: android, imageview

I am doing a app in android and i want to change the size of a Imageview when the app changes activity. After it changes activity i try to modify the size of the ImageView, but the app stops.

Any sugestions?

Comment: please post your code and stacktrace

Comment: Add code and `logcat`